# Trying to clear a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two dropdowns (select in HTML), when I select the option in the first dropdown it has to fill the second according to the id of the selected item of the first. It's doing well at removing all the previous options and filling with the id selected in the first dropdown, however it's not removing the text appearing as selected. I'm stuck at the version 1.11 of Jquery if it matters somehow. I've tried doing this both through Jquery and Javascript.

Here is the html code where the selects are:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a uf">
           <label for="cpEstado" class="select">
                 <select name="estado" id="cpEstado" data-theme="c"> <!--onchange="appUsuario.buscarCidades( this.value );">-->
                      <option value="" disabled selected>UF</option>
                  </select>
           </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b cidade">
           <label for="cpCidade" class="select">
                  <select name="cidade" id="cpCidade" data-theme="c">
                      <option value="1" disabled selected>Cidade</option>
                  </select>
           </label>
   </div>
```

Here is the Jquery function I used to fill the second dropdown:

```
$(document).on('change', '#cpEstado', function() {
    $('#cpCidade').empty();
    appUsuario.buscarCidades( this.value );});
```

When I changed the text of the selected text,

```
$("#cpCidade option:selected").html('Mudança de valor');
```

This happened. It changes the text of the item in the dropdown but not in the selected item:

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing from the bits you've provided. Use a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to provide executable code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting the value of the second dropdown (instead of setting the html content of the selected option):

```
$("#cpCidade").val('{id}');
```

Where **id** = the value of 'Mudança de valor'

Comment: Thanks, Marlon. I managed to solve the problem, it was jQuery generating a span that floats above the second dropdown and recieves the inner text of the selected option. I just set the .html() of the first dropdown to this span.